# Fill in word form field with more than 255 characters

Tags: c#, ms-word, com-interop, office-interop

I am trying to programmaticly fill in a microsoft word form. 
I am successfully able to do so if the string is under 255 chars with the following code below, however it says the string is too long if i try and use a string over 255 chars... How do I get past this limitation? If I open the word doc in word I can type in more than 255 chars without a problem. Does anyone know how to input more characters via c# code?

```
object fileName = strFileName;
object readOnly = false;
object isVisible = true;
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
//open doc
_oDoc = _oWordApplic.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing, ref readOnly,
ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
ref missing, ref missing, ref isVisible, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

_oDoc.Activate();

//write string
_oDoc.FormFields[oBookMark].Result = value;

//save and close
oDoc.SaveAs(ref fileName, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);


 _oWordApplic.Application.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my C# translation of the workaround Microsoft offers at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/163192

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
public void CreatePackage(string filePath, string longText)
{
    Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
    Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open("MyOriginalDoc.docx");
    try
    {
        //If the document is protected Select() will throw an exception
        if (doc.ProtectionType != Word.WdProtectionType.wdNoProtection)
        {
            doc.Unprotect();
        }

        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.FormField f in doc.FormFields)
        {
            //My situation prohibits me from adding bookmarks to the document, so instead I'm
            //using sentinel values that I search the doc for.
            if (f.Result.Equals("MySentinalValue"))
            {
                //You need some easily removed dummy characters in the field for this to work.
                f.Result = "****";  

                //If you don't follow these next three steps you'll end up replacing the formfield
                //rather than inserting text into it
                f.Range.Select();
                wordApp.Selection.Collapse();               
                wordApp.Selection.MoveRight(Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, 1);

                //Insert the text
                wordApp.Selection.TypeText(longText);

                //Now remove the dummy characters. If you don't re-select the range, Find won't catch the 
                //the first one.
                f.Range.Select();
                Word.Find find = wordApp.Selection.Find;
                object replaceAll = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
                find.ClearFormatting();
                find.Text = "*";
                find.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
                find.Replacement.Text = "";
                find.Execute(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref replaceAll, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            }
        //Restore the doc protections. Note that if NoReset != true all data entered in fields will be lost
        doc.Protect(Word.WdProtectionType.wdAllowOnlyFormFields, true);
        doc.SaveAs(filePath);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        doc.Close();
        wordApp.Quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this limitation could not be bypassed using the Result property of the bookmark field.
I have bypassed the problem replacing the bookmark with my text

```
// Loop on the bookmarks collection  
foreach(Bookmark bk in workDoc.Bookmarks)
{
    currentData = GetCurrentDataForBookmark(bk.Name);
    // Insert the value or cut away the bookmark if data is zero lenght
    bk.Select();
    if(currentData.Length == 0)
        _myWordApp.Selection.Cut();
    else
        _myWordApp.Selection.Text = currentData;
}
```

This approach requires that you make a copy of the orignal document and use it like a template because at the end of the update the bookmarks collection is wiped out.

Answer (score 0):

i overcome this problem by slicing the long text into 248-char size and then looping through find and replace function .. here is my code

```
int repeat;
        if (Value.Count() > 254)
            repeat = ((Value.Count() / 255));
        //string spiltedText;
        else
            repeat = 0;

        if (repeat > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= repeat; i++)
            {
                try { spiltedText = Value.Substring(i * 248, 248); spiltedText += "<الوصف>"; }
                catch { spiltedText = Value.Substring(i * 248, Value.Count() - (i * 248) - 1); }
                range.Find.Execute(findtext, findmatchcase, findmatchwholeword,
                    findmatchwildcards, findmatchsoundslike, findmatchallwordforms, findforward,
                    findwrap, findformat, spiltedText, findreplace, missing,
                    missing, missing, missing);
            }
        }

        else
        range.Find.Execute(findtext, findmatchcase, findmatchwholeword,
                findmatchwildcards, findmatchsoundslike, findmatchallwordforms, findforward,
                findwrap, findformat, spiltedText, findreplace, missing,
                missing, missing, missing);

    }
```

Notice the spiltedText size is 248 from the function Substring(),then concatenating it with <الوصف> -which will make it 255-char size- the word i`ll search for and replace with the next spiltedText

when the left long text is less than 248 it will throw and exception leading you to the catch statement , which will Substring the last less-248-chars into spiltedText without adding <الوصف> the word that will search for..

the code is tested :)